# PHP For loop skips the first outcome

Tags: php

I'm trying to fill an array with a for loop. This is done to get the amount of pages a certain book has. but when executing the code, it skips the first object in the array. Can anyone tell me why? (I thought it was because $i starts at 1 instead of 0 but that doesn't seem to change anything)

```
if(!empty($article['finishing'])){
    $numPages = $article['copies'];
    $arrayIndexNumber = [];

    for($i=1; $i <= $numPages; $i++){
        $arrayIndexNumber[] = $i;
    }

    if(count($arrayIndexNumber) >= 1 ){

        if(count($arrayIndexNumber) == 1){
            $output['attributes']['EFPageRange'] = 1;
            $print_jobs[$article['id']][] = $output;
        }

        if(count($arrayIndexNumber) > 1){
            $comma_separated1 = implode(", ", ['1', $article['copies']]);
            $output['attributes']['EFPageRange'] = $comma_separated1;
            $print_jobs[$article['id']][] = $output;
        }

        array_shift($arrayIndexNumber);
        array_pop($arrayIndexNumber);
        $comma_separated2 = implode(", ", $arrayIndexNumber);
        $output['attributes']['EFPageRange'] = $comma_separated2;

        if(count($arrayIndexNumber) >= 2){
            $print_jobs[$article['id']][] = $output;
        }
    }
    $article['file_url'] =  'i has finishing';
    $output['attributes']['username'] = $article['file_url'];
}
```

above code outputs:

```
[0] => Array
   (
      [attributes] => Array
          (
              [title] => 277569
              [EFPrintSize] => a4
              [num copies] => 1
              [num pages] => 119
              [EFPCName] => 80
              [EFDuplex] => TopTop
              [EFPageRange] => 1, 119
          )

  )
```

instead of:

```
[0] => Array
  (
      [attributes] => Array
          (
              [title] => 277564
              [EFPrintSize] => a4
              [num copies] => 1
              [num pages] => 45
              [EFPCName] => 80
              [EFDuplex] => false
              [EFPageRange] => 1, 45
              [username] => i has finishing
              [EFColorMode] => Grayscale
          )

  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first array element is deleted because of array_shift:

```
array_shift($arrayIndexNumber);
```

> [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)
>
> array_shift — Shift an element off
>   the beginning of array

Debug your code:

```
for($i=1; $i <= $numPages; $i++){
    $arrayIndexNumber[] = $i;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayIndexNumber); // Check what the array returns
```

Comment: That applies even if it already executed    $print_jobs[$article['id']][] = $output; ?

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? The part mentioned above is not executed?

Comment: [username] is skipped on the first output

Comment: output of the debug = ' [0] => 1 '

Comment: Where is `$attributes` declared outside this if statement?

Comment: it's declared nowhere, it's used as a name to identify what 'attributes' a book has/needs

Answer (score -1):

php array indexes starts to count from zero

```
for($i=1; $i <= $numPages; $i++)
      ^^^
```

change it to `$i=0`

Comment: By doing so, my "PageRange" attribute won't match anymore

Comment: i just told where are you doing wrong. if normal iteration doesn't work and breaking your rest of code, you should fix those parts where you did break the the normal logic flow. do not fight me, do not fight php's internal logic - just go and fix the wrong logic based on wrong assumptions -))

Comment: Just because indizies start at zero, it doesnt mean every loop working with arrays needs to start at zero.

Comment: ofcourse, you might want to skip first n records thus your loop will become `for($i=20, $i<$foo, $i++) {  }`. but @DannyDriesen is exploring to see why first element (at zeroth position on array) is not counted, and I explained verily this issue.